# How do I combine tapply with a function that includes replicate, sample and sum?

Tags: r, replicate, tapply

I have a csv file which has details about students and their weights from different schools

e.g.

```
School  School code Weight  Age Height
A   1   91  15  1.6
A   1   60  16  2.0
B   2   61  14  1.8
B   2   92  13  1.7
B   2   67  14  1.5
B   2   56  15  1.7
C   3   95  16  1.7
C   3   72  17  1.5
A   1   62  15  2.0
A   1   96  15  1.9
D   4   84  17  2.0
D   4   51  17  1.6
D   4   99  18  1.6
C   3   79  17  1.8
C   3   83  17  2.0
C   3   81  16  1.9
D   4   93  17  1.6
D   4   62  18  1.5
B   2   98  14  2.0
B   2   73  13  1.6
```

I would like to repeatedly sample n weights with replacement, sum my n weights and then work out the 95th quantile of the resulting distribution. I would like to do this for students within each of the 200 of the schools, varying n fro 1-25 to end up with the following output:

```
n=1 2   3   4   …   25
School code =1                  
2                   
3                   
4           95th percentile of distrinution     
5                   
…                   
200
```

I am using tapply() to find the n=1 answer for all 200 schools

```
tapply(weight,schoolcode,quantile,probs=0.95)
```

and I am using replilcate(), sum() and sample() to simulate 1000 combinations of adding two weights together.

```
nstudents=replicate(1000, sum(sample(weight, size=n, replace=TRUE)
```

I am having trouble combining the two above so that to replicate sum and sample within the tapply function.

Please advise.

I am a beginner to R.

Answer (score 2):

Put it in a function, and use that function with `tapply()`, eg:

```
Myrepfun <- function(x,n){
    nstudents <- replicate(1000,sum(sample(x, size=n,replace=TRUE)))
    quantile(nstudents,probs=0.95)
}

tapply(weight,schoolcode,Myrepfun,n=2)
```

This gives you the 0.95 quantile for every school. If you're thinking of bootstrapping, you might want to check:

http://www.statoo.com/en/publications/bootstrap_scgn_v131.pdf

http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/bootstrapping.html

to get some ideas of what else is possible.

Comment: Thanks, Will that only sample within the schhol that is specified by schoolcode?

Comment: That was what you wanted, right? So yes, it does what you asked. Try reading the code: you apply the function `Myrepfun` to the vector weight, split up according to the vector schoolcode. So `tapply` passes each time only the weights of a specific `schoolcode` as the argument `x` of the function `Myrepfun`.

Comment: Brilliant!Thanks, is there a way of varing from n=2 to n=25 by iterating? (maybe a for loop?)